# Why are variables inside functions visible to callback functions declared inside that function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a colleague ask me why he couldn't access an event parameter from a callback function.  Turns out that jquery seems to be setting the event to null after the call finishes and creating a temporary local variable fixed the problem (see below).

Then that got me thinking, why is 'message' even available to the callback.  Can someone please explain?

```
$('some seletor').click({msg: message},function(event){
    alert(event.data.msg); //event.data.msg is not available to the json callback because event is null
    var message = event.data.msg; //message will be available to the callback...why?
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
        alert(message); //works ok - why is the message variable visible here at all, should it not have gone out of scope when the above function ended?
        alert(event.data.msg); //will crash, seems that event has been set to null by the framework after the function finished
    });    
});
```

Comment: Because of closures. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: +1 for Klaus also (that was the link I used to understand it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any variable that exists in a given scope is available to all functions that are defined within that scope. (This is just how scope is defined to work in JS, [this part of the language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) is probably a good entry point if you want the nitty gritty of how it is defined).

Since the function expression that defines the callback is inside the function that defines the variable, the variable is available to it.

Comment: for others, the link that klaus gave is better for understanding closures (see comment on original question)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('some seletor').click({msg: message},function(ev){
    alert(ev.data.msg);
    var message = ev.data.msg;
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
        alert(message);
        alert(ev.data.msg);
    });    
});
```

instead of `event`. Because event is global object `window.event` and it becomes undefined when event finishes. You can use event object without taking it from parameter like this:

```
$('some seletor').click({msg: message},function(){
    alert(event.data.msg);   
});
```

Comment: I answered why event variable was not available.

Comment: Ok. That was not the question though.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen that was exactly a question. if he uses `ev` instead of `event`,then `alert(ev.data.msg);` will not crash

Comment: `Then that got me thinking, why is 'message' even available to the callback. Can someone please explain?` As far as I can read, he is asking why the variable `message` is available to the callback function. Not why the `event` gets overwritten.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen his asked that question because behavior was different. if `event` variable was also available, he would not ask that, don't you agree?

Comment: No, not really. I think he is confused because he doesn't understand javascript scopes. I think that's why he asked `Can someone explain` instead of `How do I fix this`.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen When he writes this: `$('some seletor').click({msg: message},function(event){` this means he does not understand what `event` object is

Comment: Yes that is correct. I still don't think that was the main question though, but good that you pointed it out. +1.

Comment: @karaxuna, agree with klaus, this did not answer the original question but now I understand the event problem also, cheers +1

Answer (score 0):

If you forgive the pseudo code - try thinking of it as nested blocks - this sort of thing

```
function foo()
{
  int bar=0;

  //inner block
  {
    bar++;
  }

}
```

or more specifically

```
function click()
{
 variable {msg: message}

  //inner block
  function(ev) 
  {
   ....     
  }
}
```